# Push new view controller programmatically from within didSelectRow method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm building a meme generator that employs a `tableView` and a `collectionView` for viewing saved memes. When the user taps a cell within the tableView the image should be presented by sliding the view from the previous controller not by presenting modally as a new view, which is the case. Here is my current code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let meme = memes[indexPath.row]
        let detailController = UIStoryboard(name: "DetailsStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController
        present(detailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        detailController.detailsImageView.image = meme.memedImage
    }
```

Everything I am finding is depending on using a segue, which I am not. Can I use a segue within the didSelectRow method? [Here](https://github.com/andrewTuzson/memeGenerator) is a link to the repo.

Comment: You can definitly use a segue from within didSelect Row. Is this really the question you are asking?

Comment: It is, yes. I am unsure if I can use that and also pass the data that I currently have in my didSelectRow method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `UINavigationController` to push the controller.

And second thing you can't set image to `DetailsViewController` from TableView didSelect method.

Instead you can pass this image to `DetailsViewController` and set this image in particular controller.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let meme = memes[indexPath.row]
            let detailController = UIStoryboard(name: "DetailsStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController") as! DetailsViewController
           detailController.memeImage = meme.memedImage //Pass image like this
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailController, animated: true)           
        }
```

In `DetailsViewController` do like this

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

  //Add one memeImage variable
  var memeImage: UIImage?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       detailsImageView.image = memeImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jaydeep. That makes more sense now. detailController.memeImage = meme.memedImage throws an error though. Xcode is saying that "Value of type 'DetailsViewController' has no member memeImage"

Comment: yes because you have to defined one UIImage type variable into DetailViewController

Comment: would i need to define that as an optional or no?

Comment: @AndrewTuzson . If your data can be nil then make it optional.

Comment: In my detailsViewController file I added "var meme: Meme?" and I am still receiving the same error. Why would that error be firing? The type Meme has a memedImage variable.

Comment: Thanks @Jaydeep. I updated, but I am still throwing the error. The app runs, but when you select a saved meme, nothing happens. I pushed the changes to the repo.

Comment: @AndrewTuzson Can you tell me what error is occured?

Comment: I relaunched xCode and the error is gone. However, when I tap on the saved meme, the image is not being displayed.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162731/push-new-view-controller-programmatically-from-within-didselectrow-method Joined this let we try to solve your error

Comment: @AndrewTuzson your issue is solved please check in Room